# Span only text in a HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, background, background-color

Is possible span only the text in a HTML table?
I need that the text span in 3 columns but I must keep the background color of the cells different: example first cell red, secon cell green third cell red

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="red">abcdefgh</td>
    <td bgcolor="green"></td>
    <td bgcolor="red"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: You may want to try adding an image to show your desired outcome, because the explanation, to me, seems unclear. Consider taking a look at "*[ask]*," and then perhaps [edit] your question?

Comment: It's not possible to use colspan and 2 more td's. You could create 3 'fake cells' using another element inside the td with colspan.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Are you saying that you want the text ('abcdefgh') to span across all three cells (red, green, red)? So basically for the text to break out of its cell somehow?

Comment: I have added a picture of the result that I want

Comment: That is not how tables work so there is nothing with colspan that is going too make that work. You could look at adding the text in another element and absolutely positioning it. Or maybe rethink your code to not use tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a linear gradient  for the background of the first/spanned cell that uses abrupt changes between the different colors (and delete the superfluous empty cells):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.x {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #FF0101 0% 33.33%, #5BA25F 33.34% 66.66%, #FF0101 66.67% 100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="x">abcdefghoiuasdfijawerhkgkjbyxc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cleaner than the solution I was thinking of.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you